# Visual Studio installer won't go past splash screen

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, installation, uninstallation, splash-screen

I have visual studio 2013 ultimate installed and recently uninstalled visual studio 2015 community, to upgrade to enterprise 2015.

I had trouble uninstalling 2015, but eventually running the setup and choosing for repair/uninstall did the job. This didn't work for 2013 so I haven't been able to uninstall 2013 yet.

Anyhow, when I try to install enterprise I just get the splash screen for a few seconds, and then it disappears and nothing happens. Which was also the case when I tried to uninstall either visual studio versions earlier.

[image]

Why is visual studio such a pain to install/uninstall and how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error I could see the splash screen then it dissapeared and the executable just continued running in the background but no GUI was shown.

A full uinstall and reinstall did not solve the issue.

I solved it by completely removing all the registry settings for Visual Studio 2015 that can be found under:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
Remove all subdirectories with `14` in them:

[image]

Now when restarting you get to log into your MSDN account and the GUI starts working after that.